# Modifying instance of class in its method changes caller variables too

Tags: java, variables, instance

I am not sure if I get this right, but I have a method in my class in which I create an instance of the class to hold data because of some switching. However when I call it from somewhere:

```
public static void otherClassMethod(MyClass myClass) {
    MyClass m = myClass.doStuff(); // 1
}

public class MyClass {

    private Item myItem;
    private int mCount;


    public void add(Item item) {
        if (mCount == 0) {
            myItem = item;
            myItem.setNext(null); // 2
            mCount++;
        } else {
            ....
        }
    }

    public MyClass doStuff() {
        if (mCount == 0) return null;
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        Item i = myItem;
        do {
            m.add(i); // 3
            i = i.getNext(); // 4
        } while (i != null);
        return m;
    }
}
```

In (4) it changes variables (2) both for m from (3) and myClass from (1), why (1) too?
I do not know what exactly I do not get here, can you give me a hint?
Thanks.

Comment: You are modifying the same _reference_ to an object in each method, which points to the same location in memory. You're not getting a new object when you assign it to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Both variables you are referring to are same. Because every time you are calling `doStuff()` method you create new instance of `MyClass` and return it.
It is this instance that gets changed at (1) and (3).

If you want to modify specific instance only, try passing it to `doStuff()` method instead of creating new instance. Something like this:

```
    public void doStuff(MyClass s){
        //..
    }
```

Now when you call this method, only the instance that you passed to method will change.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys @Ryan J, @hitz. I totaly forgot that it is a object which is passing, so references to values from it are same.

I changed (3) from:

```
    m.add(i);
```

to:

```
    m.add(new Item(i.getA(), ..));
```

If someone is looking for answer:

```
    Object a = new Object();
    Object b = a; // they are refering to the same reference, so they will change as one

    Object c = new Object(a.getParam()); // set through a constructor parameter
    Object d = new Object();
    d.setParam(a.getParam()); // set through setter and getter
```